# Vote count on linked / related questions

Tags: support

In some questions, the sidebar listing related and linked questions shows vote counts. On other questions it doesnt. Why are they sometimes displayed and sometimes not? Is there some criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed it's a feature that is currently being rolled out.

I spotted it on MSO earlier, seems to creep all over the network slowly.